# I need to find the smallest lambda for which $P(X\ge 2)=0.99$ when $X\sim \text{Poisson}(λ)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What I have tried to do is this:

Since $P(X>=2)=0.99$, then $P(X<2)=0.01$, Hence $P(X=0)+P(X=1)=0.01$, so replacing in the pmf, I got $\exp(-λ)+λ\exp(-λ)=0.01$, $g(λ)=\exp(-λ)+λ\exp(-λ)-0.01$. If I compute the derivative: I got

$g'(λ)=-\exp(-λ)-λ\exp(-λ)+ \exp(-λ)=-λ\exp(-λ)$, then $g'(λ)=0$, to find the minimun, I got:
$-λ\exp(-λ)=0$, I got $λ=0$, and it can´t be possible because $λ>0$, what am I doing wrong?

Also I compute I did $\ln(\exp(-\lambda)(1+\lambda))=\ln(0.01)$ and I got $\ln(\exp(-λ))+\ln(1-λ))=\ln(0.01)$ and then I got $-λ+\ln(1-λ)=-4.6$, so $g(λ)=-λ+\ln(1+λ)+4.6$, $g´(λ)=1+\frac{1}{1+λ}=0$ and then I got $λ=-2$, which can´t be possible either

Comment: What you are missing is that you need to solve $g(\lambda)=0$ subject to the constraint $\lambda>0$. If the constraint was equality, you could use the Lagrange multipliers. To handle the inequality constraints you will need to apply [KKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions.

Comment: $g(\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}=0.01$
Lagrange function:
$L(\lambda1,\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}-0.01-\lambda1(\lambda-0)$

I am getting these KKT conditions:

A)$\lambda$>0

B)$∂L/∂x=-\lambda  e^{-\lambda}-\lambda1=0$

C)$\lambda1(\lambda)=0$

D)$\lambda1>=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one $λ$ for which $P(X>=2)=0.99$ as $P(X=k)$ in a Poisson distribution is a deterministic equation.

This means solving:

$exp(−λ)+λexp(−λ)=0.01$ which gives a value of $λ=6.64$

[image]

Testing this value we get that $P(X=0)+P(X=1)=exp(-6.64)(7.64)=0.01$

So $λ=6.64$
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, How did you get λ=6.64?

Comment: @Peterson I ploted the equation with Geogebra and looked for the point where the ecuation crossed the x-Axis. But probably any calculator or computer program can numericaly solve the equation. As stated in the answer Daryl gave you could do it with Wolphram Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find $\lambda$ that satisfies your condition, you need to solve $g(\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}+\lambda e^{-\lambda}=0.01$. This equation requires a numerical method (or you could use the LambertW function) to determine $\lambda$.

The plot of this function can be seen at [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2B1%29*exp%28-x%29-0.01+for+x+from+0+to+10&x=-988&y=-71). This graph shows the first time $g(\lambda)=0.01$ is around $\lambda=7$ with $\lambda>0$. Solving the equation with [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28x%2B1%29*exp%28-x%29-0.01+for+x+&x=-988&y=-71) gives the solution in terms of the LambertW function and the numerical approximation.